# jQuery: changing link text on success

Tags: jquery

In showComments (), an ajax call and on success i tried:

```
$('#showCommentLink').text("Hide");
```

Im trying to change the text from show all comments to "hide" without results.

```
<a class='showCommentLink' href='javascript:showComments($displayWall[id]);' style='cursor: pointer;'>Show all $isThereAnyComments comments</a>
```

Have i missed something?

Comment: Is this PHP? You have variables in your HTML. If it is PHP, separate out array variables with curly bracket notation `<?php echo "...Comments({$displayWall[$id]});' style..."; ?>`... Additionally your forget the dollar sign (`$`) in front of `id`. -------- Finally, don't use inline JS. Separate it out. It'll be easier to maintain and it's more accessible.

Answer (score 3):

`$('.showCommentLink')` not `$('#showCommentLink')`.

The `#` selector is for IDs, and the `.` selector is for classes.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.showCommentLink').text("Hide");
```

You used #, which looks for an id. "." looks for a class.

Also, you should read up on onobtrusive javascript - running that function in your href kind of defeats a major purpose of jquery!